# notification on android when you receive a file

Tags: android, image, file, notifications

I am making an Android application for a picture viewer. My problem is that i don't know how to have a new notification when a new picture is received in a specific folder. How does a notification appear on the notification bar when a new picture is received?

Comment: Narrow your question. 1, Did you know how to display notification?

Answer (score 0):

Well one easy way would be use preferences and save the count of pictures and then check that count on a regular basis.If count is greater than the value stored in the preference then generate a notification and update the preference value, else do nothing.